# Cutting child divs as circle

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a neat loading bar, but for that I need your help.

I'm trying to accomplish something in css that looks like this:
[image: What I'm trying to accomplish]
With the following html:

```
<div class="example">
  <div class="example-inner"></div>
  <div class="example-inner"></div>
  <div class="example-inner"></div>
  <div class="example-inner"></div>
  <div class="example-inner"></div>
</div>
```

Here's what I managed to do so far(it's not much, I know): [Codepen](http://codepen.io/NonameSL/pen/PGjBkJ) / Direct view for you lazy ones:

```css
.example{
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333;
}
.example-inner{
  width:100%;
  height:20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <div class="example-inner"></div>
  <div class="example-inner"></div>
  <div class="example-inner"></div>
  <div class="example-inner"></div>
  <div class="example-inner"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `overflow:hidden` to the parent.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.example {
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* add this */
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.example-inner {
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <div class="example-inner"></div>
  <div class="example-inner"></div>
  <div class="example-inner"></div>
  <div class="example-inner"></div>
  <div class="example-inner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

just add overflow:hidden in example

```
.example{
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```